# PHPunit ignores onDelete set null in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have a Laravel setup where I try to build everything using Test Driven Development.

**Setup**

I have a migration where I create a table of categories which can be a parent or child of other categories. When I delete a parent category, all the childs should become root categories. To accomplish this I created a foreign key which has `set null` as value for the `onDelete`.

**Problem**

When I test this behaviour in MySQL it works as expected, but when I run a test with PHPunit it fails. Can anyone help me figure out where I made a mistake or isn't this possible at all?

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('categories', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string('name', 100);

    $table->unsignedInteger('parent_id')->nullable();

    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('set null');
});
```

**Testfile**

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class CategoryTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function aCategoryBecomesRootWhenParentIsDeleted()
    {
        $category = Category::create(['name' => 'test_category_6']);

        $child_category = Category::create(['name' => 'test_category_7', 'parent_id' => $category->id]);

        $category->delete();

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('categories', ['id' => $child_category->id, 'parent_id' => NULL]);
    }

}
```

**phpunit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"></env>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"></env>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: what database do you have set for testing? sqlite?

Comment: @lagbox yes. I added my PHPunit config as well, maybe there is some more information in there.

Comment: does sqlite have this functionality on the foreign key by default? i feel it is something that has to be enabled

Comment: I think you need to enable foreign keys, because by default they are turned off. *Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards compatibility)...* [source](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

Comment: @lagbox Weird, I just tested it with a sqlite database and a sqlite db browser and it works as expected. Maybe not for the PHPunit test, but I think I can work towards a solution now thanks to you and Kyslik!

Comment: @Kyslik See the above comment. I think I can solve the issue now!

Comment: No problem, good luck! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comments of lagbox and Kyslik, I was able to create a solution to this problem.

My test suite uses SQLite, which has foreign keys disabled by default, apparently for backwards compatibility. To ensure my test suite is the same as my normal environment I added the following code to the `TestCase` class:

```
/**
 * Enables foreign keys.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function enableForeignKeys()
{
    $db = app()->make('db');
    $db->getSchemaBuilder()->enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
```

Next, I added this line to the `setup` method of that same class:

```
$this->enableForeignKeys();
```

This enables me to use the foreign keys in the test environment.